# How to install CPU-G on Ubuntu

Tags: system, monitoring

How to install [CPU-G](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpug/) on Ubuntu , so i can use it to view information about my desktop hardware .

Answer (score 11):

In newest versions of Ubuntu (mine Linux Mint 18), try this:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpu-g`

Comment: "Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default."

Answer (score 4):

To install Cpu-G , useful utility to show hardware information. It detects hardware and display details about everything, it shows information about CPU(Processor), RAM(Active/Inactive, Free, Used and cached), Motherboard and Chipset, Bios Details, Graphic card details .

In Terminal :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cpug-devs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpu-g
```

Open it :

[image]

You can view information about :

[image]

[image]

[Reference](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/cpuz-alternatives-inex-cpug-for-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Thank you , but "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." -> "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Comment: This answer is out of date - the packages have moved

Comment: The cpu-g package started to download manually from ppa:cpug-devs/ppa when I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Although i find that @nux gave the good answer, i have to indicate a simple way  to install CPU-G for people  without use of add-apt-repository  utility. In that case  the   [CPU-G sourceforge](http://cpug.sourceforge.net/)   tarball or  [CPU-G deb](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/10/cpu-z-for-ubuntu-cpu-g.html) download is a convenient way

Comment: This answer is also out of date. As is the above answer.