# CPU-G crashing on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cpu

I'm new to linux (but loving it), and I'm trying to use cpu-g. I've followed the installation procedures on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433880/how-to-install-cpu-g-on-ubuntu) but after installation, clicking on the cpu-g icon, the software crashes with the following details. Any ideas to solve this? Thanks in advance !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install GCC.

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I've just installed ubuntu, and gcc did not come naturally.

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved :)